# How to use a maven module (created by user) in your main project in intelliJ-idea?

Tags: java, maven, pdf, intellij-idea, itext

For my project I need to generate some PDFs for which I'm using iText. To work with iText in IntelliJ-idea 2019, I created a new maven module. My main project is ready but I can't understand how should I access my maven module (I created) from my main program to create PDFs.
The module I created is named as pdfgenerator and the main program is the src directory (which has BCrypt, automailer, calculator etc.).

[image]

EDIT : I'm aware that this question might be a repeated one, but I want to know a method which is simple to implement and easy to understand.

EDIT2 2 : If there's an alternative to creating a maven module then please suggest, my prime target is to get the code working in the simplest way possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447590/combining-a-maven-project-with-a-java-project

Comment: @HasanuzzamanRana thank you for the link but can you please elaborate ??? I didn't quite understand properly what's written there.

Comment: moreover I'm interested in knowing a simple and fast method, which is easy to understand.

Comment: You need to have a root pom.xml file that will defined the dependencies between the two maven modules you are using. Google for Maven aggregate pom.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Can you please share some links about how to use maven and everything about maven I need to know ? I really want to learn and start using it in my projects.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module